# Wildcard in filename keeps failing in my shell script

Tags: shell-script

**Scenario:** I'm logging into a docker container to restore a mongodb dump. There is only one dump file in the volume.

If I use a wild card in the file name I get the errors below but if I give the full file name it works. I've spent a few hours searching forums but can't find an answer. What is missing from my script?

```
root@141782f66c37:/data/backup# ./mongoretore.sh
./mongoretore.sh: line 2: dump_06-11-2020_20-32-15.dump: command not found
./mongoretore.sh: line 2: `*.dump`: ambiguous redirect
```

**WORKING**

```
#!/bin/bash
mongorestore --drop --archive < dump_06-11-2020_20-32-15.dump
```

**NOT WORKING**

```
#!/bin/bash
mongorestore --drop --archive < `*.dump`
```

Comment: The first error message shows that *.dump is being expanded, and then treated as an executable command (which does not exist because the file is not executable (and is not an ELF or shebanged file). The second error message results because the failed command produces no output, so the < has no operand. The back-ticks should not be there.

Comment: Thank you but I don't know what to do with the information you provided. Leaving out the backticks dumps returns the error `./mongoretore.sh: line 2: *.dump: ambiguous redirect` and I can't find anything that leads me a working solution with your comment `being expanded, and then treated as an executable`. Do you have a suggestion on a working like would be?

Comment: First, get rid of the backticks so that the shell doesn't interpret it as an executable command. Second, make sure that it is the only `.dump` file in the directory or else it will attempt to redirect every file in the directory that ends in `.dump` to the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
... < `*.dump`
```

The part after the redirection operator here is a command substitution, better written with the more modern syntax as `$(*.dump)`. Inside of it is a shell glob. The glob expands all filenames that end with `.dump`, and they're then taken as a command to run.

In your case, the resulting command is `dump_06-11-2020_20-32-15.dump`, by itself if it's the only matching file, or with other file names following if there are others. In any case, your `PATH` does not contain a command with that name, so the shell gives an error. Then it gives another error, since the redirection fails. Possibly because the command substitution outputs an empty string, so it's like doing

```
x=
... < $x
```

Now, the question is, what are you trying to do? Usually, you'd not try to run files in the working directory as commands with a plain `*`, since the current directory is not often in `PATH`, so it would not work. If you only intend to have a file with a know name read, the correct syntax is without the backticks, e.g.

```
... < filename.dump
```

Or, if you don't know the file name, but know you only have one, you can use a glob:

```
... < *.dump
```

This will work as long as there is exactly one matching file in the directory. With more, it'll give an `ambiguous redirect` error, since Bash can't know which one you mean to read from.

If there can be more than one file, you'll need to decide what to do with them. Run the command once for each file, with input redirected from each in turn? Or run the command just once in total, with input redirected from one of the files? But which one?

Comment: there is only ever one dump file in the folder. My pipeline places the latest DB dump in that folder and so I just needed a script to use whatever dump file it finds. That way I don't have to keep editing the script or manually type the command and my docker build can run the script. `... < *.dump` also returns an `ambiguous redirect` but this works `cat *.dump | mongorestore --drop --archive`

Comment: @chrisloughnane, well, the cases I can figure out where Bash would give that `ambiguous redirect` from a redirection with a pattern is either that there's more than one file matching, or `shopt -s nullglob` is in effect and there are no files that match.

Comment: @chrisloughnane, so, can you double-check that there's indeed just one file? What does `ls -l *.dump` show? Or `shopt` and `echo $BASH_VERSION` for that matter?

Comment: I rebooted my system and cloned my project into a fresh folder and started from scratch. I can confirm my script with `mongorestore --drop --archive < *.dump` is working and that I can run this script from the host with `docker exec -w /data/backup -it mongolinks /bin/bash -c "./mongorestore.sh"` and my db is restored. The logical answer is I must have had another .dump file there although I didn't see it in my file manager. Thanks for your help, I learned a lot more about shell scripting.

Comment: @chrisloughnane, if you have `shopt -s dotglob` enabled, the glob will also match names that start with a dot (so `.blahblah.dump`) but a file manager might consider them hidden and not show them. Where you'd come up with one, well, I have no idea, but that's one of the possibilities. And the reason I asked what `ls -l *.dump` and `shopt` show :)

Comment: @chrisloughnane ".. latest DB dump in that folder" ?? Being as its name is unique (it includes a timestamp to the nearest second), what is the strategy to remove dumps from previous runs, to ensure "there is only ever one dump file in the folder"? My usual is "As soon as a file is successfully processed, automatically move it into a subdirectory `./done`, and touch it so you know exactly when it was processed."

Comment: I assumed from the context that dealing with old files was done somehow. However, even if files are moved/deleted after processing, it can still happen that the processing fails, leaving an extra file to mess up the glob.

Comment: @ilkkachu Quite so. I also used to loop over all files that matched the relevant pattern, processing the oldest file each time. There was also a stage where I checked file sizes every five minutes until they ceased to change, to deal with incomplete FTP transfers. Nevertheless, looking for multiple .dump files in file manager is inadequate for production systems. The eyeball is vastly inferior to the glob.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I like that, moving the processed file to an archive folder. Cheers.